# Rigid Body Chain and Pendant Breaking

Tags: animation, physics

all,

I am trying to create a chain and drape it naturally over a mannequin rather than position each individual link. I have a pendant attached to the chain, and when I bake the scene the pendant breaks from the chain.

Both chain links and pendant are active rigid body types, and I have connected everything as points chained by distance. Everything weighs the same. The chain links stay together but the pendant falls off. Is it the shape of the pendant that's causing this to happen?

Any pointers would be appreciated. I have attached the blender file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zY8HsxUqkCWdc1UAhz5zpmV4YiJ4LTnM

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by joining the pendant and the two closest links then connecting that object with the adjacent links.